# My website deployed on Vercel keeps giving me the "429: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS" errors. What could be going wrong, how can I debug this?

Tags: next.js, vercel

Occassionally (maybe about half the time) when I load a page on the [website](https://nexy.io/) I'm working on, I'm getting an error that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zm71.png).

> 429: TOO_MANY_REQUESTS
> Code: INTERNAL_FUNCTION_RATE_LIMIT
> ID: lhr1::258d8-1638206479250-0a01c8648601

My website hasn't been launched yet, almost nobody visits it but me, so it can't be having too much traffic yet.

The page I'm loading has a `getServerSideProps()` function that does only one thing - uses prisma to fetch posts from my database, which are sent to my component to be rendered.

I can't imagine what could be causing too many requests.

My vercel usage stats look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB18j.jpg).

What am I doing wrong? What could be causing this? How can I debug this?

For reference, below is all my relevant code. Any chance you could take a look at it and let me know if you have any ideas on what could be happening?

---

**index.tsx has getServerSideProps() function which calls a getPosts() function to fetch the posts.**

```js
import Layout from 'components/Layout/Layout'
import PostFeed from 'components/Posts/PostFeed'
import Subnav from 'components/Layout/Subnav'
import Pagination from 'components/Posts/Pagination'
import ProfileHeader from 'components/Users/ProfileHeader'
import TagHeader from 'components/Layout/TagHeader'
import HomeHeader from 'components/CTAs/HomeHeader'
import SubscribeBox from 'components/CTAs/SubscribeBox'
import AdBoxes from 'components/CTAs/AdBoxes'

export default function browse({ posts, postCount, username }) {
  return (
    <Layout subnav={<Subnav />}>
      <PostFeed posts={posts} />
      <Pagination postCount={postCount} />
      <AdBoxes/>
      <SubscribeBox />
      <br />
    </Layout>
  )
}

import { getPosts } from 'prisma/api/posts/get-posts'
import config from 'config.json'

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, query }) {
  const { username, sort, tag, search } = query
  const { posts, postCount } = await getPosts({
    published: true,
    searchString: search,
    username: username,
    tagSlug: tag,
    sort: sort,
    skip: config.postsPerPage * (parseInt(query.page?.toString()) - 1 || 0),
    take: config.postsPerPage,
  })
  return { props: { posts, postCount, username } }
}
```

---

**get-posts.ts runs a prisma query and fetches the posts.**

```js
import prisma from 'prisma/prismaClient'

export async function getPosts({ username, published, tagSlug, searchString, sort, skip, take }) {
  console.log(`Get posts. Sorting: ${sort}`)
  // Filter posts by user (to show them on their profile)
  let author
  if (username) author = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { username } })
  // Filter by tag
  const tagFilter = tagSlug ? {
    tags: { some: { slug: tagSlug } }
  } : {}
  // Search through posts
  const search = searchString ? {
    OR: [
      { title: { contains: searchString, mode: "insensitive", } },
      { body: { contains: searchString, mode: "insensitive", } },
      { tags: { some: { name: { contains: searchString, mode: "insensitive", } } } },
      { author: { username: { contains: searchString, mode: "insensitive", } } },
    ],
  } : {}

  let orderBy = [{ rank: 'desc' }]
  if (sort === 'new') orderBy = [{ createdAt: 'desc' }]
  if (sort === 'top') orderBy = [{ score: 'desc' }]

  const allFilters = {
    authorId: author?.id,
    published: published,
    ...search,
    ...tagFilter,
  }
  const [posts, postCount] = await prisma.$transaction([
    prisma.post.findMany({
      where: allFilters,
      orderBy: orderBy, //rank: 'desc' //score: 'desc'
      take, skip,
      include: {
        tags: true,
        author: {
          select: {
            username: true
          }
        },
        upvoters: {
          select: {
            username: true
          }
        },
        // Just for the comment counter
        comments: {
          select: {
            id: true
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    prisma.post.count({ where: allFilters })
  ])

  return { posts, postCount }
}
```

---

**the prismaClient which get-posts is using to connect to prisma**

```js
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

// PrismaClient is attached to the `global` object in development to prevent
// exhausting your database connection limit.
//
// Learn more: 
// https://pris.ly/d/help/next-js-best-practices

let prisma: PrismaClient

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient()
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient()
  }
  prisma = global.prisma
}
export default prisma
```

Comment: Do you have other projects hosted in Vercel by any chance?

Comment: @juliomalves Yeah, I have a bunch of projects, but they don't seem to have these issues. Most are static websites, and none of them get much traffic yet.

Comment: Right, I was just wondering since the concurrency limit in Vercel is shared across all projects deployed under the same team. But if their traffic is low then that might not be the cause of the 429s.

Comment: More suggestions to debug here: https://vercel.com/guides/what-should-i-do-if-i-receive-a-429-error-on-vercel

Answer (score 0):

Try going towards `getInitialProps` which will execute your function on the browser vs `getServerSideProps` which always goes to your function creating loops as customers refresh your page or traverse through the site.

As to why so many requests, i think as clients traverse your site, you are generating hits to your function in a loop.

Comment: I have plausible analytics on my website, it had 5 visitors in the last day (one of them is me), so I'm pretty sure it can't be overabundance of traffic.

And unfortunately I can't do this on the client side, it's important to me that the website is server-side rendered. It's also important to figure out the root cause - this kind of thing is not supposed to happen.

Comment: Are you able to deploy this to StackBlitz or equivalent? you can remove the prisma client piece and echo back, this will let you debug where the loop is, if you did not have visitors, this is definitely a loop - FWIW, https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps sends data initially from the server - with NextJS 9 and above `getstaticProps` is preferred, however its at build time.